# On a relaxed form of Goldbach's conjecture proposed by Erdős

Tags: nt.number-theory, goldbach-type-problems, erdos

The Goldbach's conjecture says that:

**"Every even integer greater that $2$ is the sum of two prime numbers"**.

Let $\varphi$ denote the Euler's totient function. I remember that a long time ago I read that Erdős, motivated by the identity $\varphi(p) = p - 1$ for all prime numbers $p$, asked if the following weaker form of Goldbach's conjecture is true:

**"Every positive even integer is the sum of two totients $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$ ($x$ and $y$ positive integers)"**.

Unfortunately, I do not remember any reference.

Anyway, recently this problem has came to my mind, so I am curious: **Has Erdős' question being settled?**

Comment: Since $\phi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1)$, wouldn't Chen's theorem essentially imply this conjecture?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Would you mind elaborating on how it would?

Comment: The problem is stated in the book "Unsolved Problems in Number Theory" which is written by Richard Guy; see page 105 of the book. For a new reference and some new results see "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08117.pdf".

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but one can prove fairly easily that every large positive integer is a sum of a bounded number of totients, since the set $S \oplus S$ (where $S$ is the set of totients, along with 0) has positive Schnierlmann density. This follows from the fact that $P \oplus P$ has positive Schnierlmann density, where $P$ is the set of primes along with 0 and the fact that $\phi(p) = p -1$.